# Changing background in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, background

Hey, I have a UIImageView in my app. And I I have 4 backgrounds created for the app. I want the user to be able to change between these 4 backgrounds. I found a video on youtube to give you an idea of where I'm going.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO9NRIHU6oQ

The user clicks on a button which open a new view allowing the user to scroll thru the backgrounds and when the user got finds the backround he or she wants the user taps on a button again to use it.

Any Ideas of how I would do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it could be done with a parent view controller containing a button and an imageview. The button causes a secondary view to animate up. The secondary view then has theoretically any number of imageviews (but maybe just three, a previous, a current and a next which are dynamically refreshed from an array of images). Then you just have to sync the current imageview contents with the contents of the imageview in the first view in your parent view controller.

I realize a pile of text like this is probably hard to follow, especially if you're new to iPhone programming, but do some reading into uiview and viewcontroller hierarchies and you should be able to figure something out.

Comment: Ok, Thanks! I'll see what I can get together :)